# I am having problem with Failed to find target with hash string 'android-30' in: C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to find target with hash string 'android-30' in: C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

- Try:
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to gRun with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to g
  et more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s

the problem is still showing even I had already downloded the required SDK Platform
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBMuo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm1cU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwF5E.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on ionic. I just delete all my android sdks and installed only android-30. That's work for me.
I didn't do it from Android Studio. I used sdkmanager command line on Linux.
$ANDROID_HOME is where you have android-sdk or cmdlinetools.
I also use --sdk_root because i don't have cmdlinetools in my path.

```
$ANDROID_HOME/bin/sdkmanager --uninstall "platforms;android-30" --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME
$ANDROID_HOME/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-30" --sdk_root=$ANDROID_HOME
```